# cannot find class symbol error in android studio

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments

i am trying to reference a kotlin class in a fragment class in java and it results to error saying that it cannot find the symbol of the kotlin class.
[image: 1]

> fragment class

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_flashcards, container, false);
go = (ImageButton) rootview.findViewById(R.id.goBtn);

```
        //Instructions audio
        instruct = (ImageButton) rootview.findViewById(R.id.soundBtn);
        MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.instructions);

        //Click go button to explore flashcards
        go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Flashcards1.class)); 
            }
        });
        return rootview;
    }
}
```

> this is where the error is

```
 startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Flashcards1.class));
```

> build.gradle app

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.salitongue_updated"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.7'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.1'
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.0-alpha02"
    //testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

> build.gradle

```
 buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Do you have a class called `Flashcards1.class`? (Case matters, remember!) And not that it matters for this error, but it needs to be a subclass of `Activity` (e.g. `AppCompatActivity`) for `startActivity` to work with that `Intent`

Comment: hi! yes i have a class called Flashcards1, you mean this one right? `class Flashcards1 : AppCompatActivity()`

Comment: Yeah that's it - hold on, I'll post this in an answer, since its long

Answer (score 0):

I *think* your problem is that you don't have Kotlin set up for your `app` module. You have the plugin dependency added to your *main* `build.gradle`, but you're not applying the plugin in the *`app` module* `build.gradle`. You also don't have the `kotlin-stdlib` dependency added to that module. Have a look at the [example setup here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/add-kotlin#add) (you have to scroll down a bit to the code snippets).

I don't know a lot about Gradle and the ways to configure your build files, so it's possible you've got it set up a different way and it's fine - but you *should* be able to see Kotlin class files from Java [without doing anything special](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html):

> Kotlin code can be easily called from Java. For example, instances of a Kotlin class can be seamlessly created and operated in Java methods.

So it seems like maybe it's just not set up, and that's why it's not working for you. If Kotlin's working in the IDE (like popping up in code completion) but not when you try to build it, that sounds like the IDE plugin is set up fine, but not the stuff in your project. I don't know for sure, but hopefully it'll help!

Comment: hi! thanks for sharing! i have tried adding the dependencies to my module however the error is still the same :(